# What -C flag number in perl makes UTF-8 "just work"?

Tags: perl, utf-8, utf8-decode

My setup: perl-5.20.2, UTF-8 environment.

Consider the following two bash examples. The first one works OK, the second doesn't.

```
echo -n 'привет мир' | perl -MEncode -le '$a=decode("utf8",<>); $x=decode("utf8","мир"); print encode("utf8",sprintf("% 11s",$a)) if $a=~/$x/'|grep -q ' привет мир' && echo OK
```

```
for (( i=0; $i < 512; i=$((i+1)) )); do echo -n 'привет мир' | perl -C$i -le '$a=<>; print sprintf("% 11s",$a) if $a=~/мир/' | grep -q ' привет мир' && echo $i; done
```

Why there is no -C flag number in case 2), which makes the example work at least once?

Comment: You could use `-Mutf8`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why there is no -C flag number ... which makes the example work at least once?

Because using UTF-8 literals in your Perl source requires `use utf8;`.

```
for (( i=0; $i < 512; i=$((i+1)) )); do echo -n 'привет мир' | perl -C$i -le 'use utf8; $a=<>; print sprintf("% 11s",$a) if $a=~/мир/' | grep -q ' привет мир' && echo $i; done
```

There's no `-C` value that replicates `use utf8;`.  With `use utf8` any odd value for `-C` passes the test (STDIN is assumed UTF-8), but you get a "Wide character in print" warning unless you also have STDOUT set to UTF-8.

So, `-C3` works, as does any number `$i % 4 == 3`.  For 1-liners, you probably want `-CSDA` (`-C63`) to say that all I/O and `@ARGV` should be UTF-8.

You can also use the `-Mutf8` option instead of putting `use utf8;` in your 1-liner.  `-mutf8` does not work because it is equivalent to `use utf8 ();` and the parens prevent the `import` method from being called.  Since it's the `import` method that marks your source code as UTF-8, `-mutf8` does nothing.  But `-Mutf8` is equivalent to `use utf8;` so it works.

However, putting `-Mutf8` into `PERL5OPT` may break any script that uses non-ASCII ISO-8859-1 literals.  That may be a risk you're willing to take, but you should be aware of it.

Comment: What is curious: I tried with `-mutf8`, but that did not work; `use utf8` didn't occur to me. Why `-mutf8` does not work? Is there a substitute for this pragma in perl command line options? - I would like to make an alias, as I *always* use UTF-8, and adding extra gibberish to my casual one-liners does not appeal to me.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko, I've expanded my answer to explain `-mutf8` vs. `-Mutf8`.

Comment: One detail: in the code I write `use strict`, in command line `-mstrict`. Why this inconsistency? In perl naming convention module names start with uppercase letter and pragma names start with lowercase letter, don't they?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko, you can use `-mstrict` on the command line, but it won't actually do anything.  You have to use `-Mstrict` if you really want strict mode turned on, for the same reason I gave for `-Mutf8`.